# Any way to stop Unity placing new scripts in the project root?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, project

When you add a new script to a Unity gameobject in your scene, it always places it in the root, rather than the selected folder in the Project tab. Mildly annoying but annoying all the same. Is there an option to make it place it in the selected folder instead by default?

Followup edit:
Nowadays I split the solution up into multiple projects using Assembly Definitions (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html) and add source files in Visual Studio instead of Unity, which will sync when the solution is saved. You need to make the class a MonoBehaviour by hand (or you could create a template to do it) but most of my classes aren't MonoBehaviour or inherit from a class which inherits MonoBehaviour it so its not such a big deal.

Comment: Yeah. Right click on the selected folder -> Create -> C# Script

Comment: But then you have to locate and drag it onto the object. Not a big deal as I said in the OP but would be nice if it could do it in one step.

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/614348/change-default-script-folder.html
there does not seem to be a less comlicated way yet.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution too. When I add script behavior to states, this goes at the root, and it's annoying as heck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few days ago I stumbled upon a [AssetPostporcessor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.html) approach, there was a guy who made a tool for his team to put their newly imported/created files right into proper directories to cope with asset chaos on project, and he provided the code as well. Just can't find the url on another PC. But I feel like the idea should be clear - just override `AssetPostporcessor`for `.cs` files and puth them to any other folder you like. You could even parse file, get a namespace or any other mark you wish to use, and decide exact folder. So any logic is possible theoretically.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this in the future, @Xander is correct. There does not seem to be a standard way for unity, though you may override a simple class. As for the referenced link, which he cannot find:

https://discussions.unity.com/t/change-default-script-folder/92375/6

This should explain everything (or, if you need to, allow you to simply copy paste )